# Why the domain name space tree can have only 128 levels?

Tags: networking, dns

In the book TCP/IP Protocol Suite 4ed, the author write:

> Domain Name Space Domain name space are defined in inverted tree
>   structure with root at the top the tree can have only 128 levels.

Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to implement protocols when the relevant data structures are limited in size. When DNS was designed, 128 labels was considered sufficient. Indeed, nowadays it is rare to see domains using more than 5-6 labels.

Note that a full domain name is also limited in size to 253 characters, including the dots, so even with 1-letter labels it doesn't make sense to use more labels, because it's not possible.

Now if you ask why is the total length limited to 253 characters, it was considered sufficient and it is easy to encode. For strings with less than 256 characters, you can store the length in 1 byte. This makes the binary representation of DNS names very simple and efficient.

Comment: In RFC 1035, limit of the name is 255 bytes. Is it correct?

Comment: 255 bytes in binary representation, 253 characters in textual representation. That is because fully qualified DNS names use a dot at the end (`google.com.`, not `google.com`) taking 1 byte, and one more byte is needed for null termination.